# commandline installation of virtual machine in oracle virtual box

Tags: virtualbox

Looking for command line installation of centos7 virtual machine in a host machine(centos7).

Followed several options but once the vm is created, its not able to get ip and cant access the guest machine from the host server

followed below methods

```
1. VBoxManage createvm --name centos-server --ostype Linux --register

Virtual machine 'centos-server' is created and registered.
```

UUID: 6eb514b4-a1f3-4454-9d76-2be9d0f76cb3
Settings file: '/root/VirtualBox VMs/centos-server/centos-server.vbox'

```
2. VBoxManage modifyvm centos-server --bridgeadapter1 vmnet1
```

3.

VBoxManage modifyvm centos-server --memory 2048

4

VBoxManage createhd --filename VirtualBox\ VMs/centos-server/centos-server.vdi --size 10000 --format VDI

0%...10%...20%...30%...40%...50%...60%...70%...80%...90%...100%
Medium created. UUID: adae09bb-d01b-42ee-9383-69ef59b2cbf6
    ===== /root/VirtualBox VMs/VirtualBox VMs/centos-server/centos-server.vdi

5. VBoxManage storagectl centos-server --name "SATA Controller" --add sata --controller IntelAhci

6.

VBoxManage storageattach centos-server --storagectl "SATA Controller" --port 0 --device 0 --type hdd --medium VirtualBox\ VMs/centos-server/centos-server.vdi
if not working

VBoxManage storageattach centos-server --storagectl "SATA Controller" --port 0 --device 0 --type hdd --medium "/root/VirtualBox VMs/VirtualBox VMs/centos-server/centos-server.vdi"

7.

VBoxManage storagectl centos-server --name "IDE Controller" --add ide --controller PIIX4

8.

VBoxManage storageattach centos-server --storagectl "IDE Controller" --port 1 --device 0 --type dvddrive --medium /opt/CentOS-7-x86_64-DVD-1908.iso

9.

VBoxManage startvm centos-server --type headless

getting error as below

Waiting for VM "centos-server" to power on...
VBoxManage: error: VT-x is not available (VERR_VMX_NO_VMX)
VBoxManage: error: Details: code NS_ERROR_FAILURE (0x80004005), component ConsoleWrap, interface IConsole

Comment: Hi Experts, any help on the auto provisioning of vms in virtual box with connectivity between host to guests and vice versa with internet enabled in guests?

Comment: i could resolve the error by downgrading virtual box from 6 to 5.2 version. Now i am able to start the vms. But now not able to get ip assigned to the guest vm and not able to connect it from host